# Understanding the output number of digits when dividing two floats

Tags: objective-c, c, floating-point

I'm trying to compare a float-result from a division with another float which is identical to the output but when I compare them I get an unmatching result.

Here is what I have...

```
float num1 = 7.000000;
float num2 = 15.000000;
float result = num1 / num2;

NSLog(@"Result: %f", result);// output Result: 0.466667    

float num3 = 0.466667;

if (result == num3)
{
   NSLog(@"Equal");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"NOT Equal");
}
```

As you can see I'm comparing the result from the division with an identical number but when I do the comparison I get "NOT Equal",  but if I change num3 to 0.4666666667 the comparison becomes "Equal" which I understand is the right answer.

My question is, why does the output of the result comes as 0.466667 and not as 0.4666666667 if it is really what the result should be?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Floating point..  Did you try comparing `0.1 + 0.2` and `0.3` yet?

Comment: you should not compare floating point values for equality.. use greater/lesser operators for comparison

Comment: If you just specify `%f` not all digits are shown; it's a trade-off between precision and readability. You can specify a precision like `%.20f` to see more digits and you'll see that your floating-point division yields 0.46666666865..., which is neither 0.466667 nor 7/15.

Comment: The key is understanding floating point numbers. Not all decimal numbers can be expressed with complete accuracy in floating point. This typically occurs with non-whole decimal numbers. Google floating point numbers and learn the details.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. Is there a way to control the number of digits of the output but at the same time make it hold its output value? I would like to be able to work with only 6 digits.

Comment: This same basic question is asked probably once a day.  You cannot "set" the precision of a floating-point number -- the precision is defined by the specific number format (Google "IEEE floating point").  You also should (almost) never use `==` to compare two floats, since if you've done any computations at all you've probably lost some precision and "equal" values will actually differ in the low-order bits.

Comment: See http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: This is a topic that is apparently short-changed by many programming instructors.  When I was first taught programming (FORTAN IV on an IBM 1800) the prof spent at least an hour (maybe more, it's been a few years) going over the peculiarities of floating-point and drumming into our heads that you should never compare floats for equality.

Comment: Thank you all for the good information.